# Theme Image Style for image located in module directory

Tags: 7, media

Probably coming at this from too much of a Drupal 6 view point but...

How do I theme an image in a given image style when that image lives in a module folder?  This is driving me batty and I know I'm just missing something simple.

Here is some example code showing what I'm trying to do:

```
$file_uri = 'public://sites/all/modules/my_module/logo.jpg';
$data['logo'] = theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'medium', 'path' => $file_uri));
```

Even if I use file_build_uri(), I end up with a path to a file that doesn't exist. If I move the image to the files directory and change the $file_uri to 'public://logo.jpg', it works just fine.

Do I need to copy the image to the files directory as part of the module code?  If so, isn't this ridiculous?

What am I missing?  Is there documentation on how to do something like this?  I've spent over an hour mining the Drupal documentation and came up completely dry.

Comment: public://sites/all/modules/my_module/logo.jpg effectively translates to sites/default/files/sites/all/modules/my_module/logo.jpg - which is why the above doesn't work.

Guess the question I have is, how do I avoid copying the file just to run it through theme_image_style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that's by design. From the [`theme_image_style()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) docs' description of the acceptable parameters:

> path: The path of the image file **relative to the Drupal files directory. This function does not work with images outside the files directory nor with remotely hosted images**. This should be in a format such as 'images/image.jpg', or using a stream wrapper such as 'public://images/image.jpg'.

Emphasis mine.

It seems the image style system only works in the context of the public files directory (maybe private too, I'm not sure).

I ran into a similar situation recently and ended up having to code it myself (although I borrowed a lot from the core image module).

Comment: Thanks - really wish it didn't work this way but I suppose I can reason out why the developers chose this approach.

Answer (score 9):

I just came across this and had to write the code to handle this.

This effectively clones `theme_image_style()` to create image derivatives during execution of the page request. Generation bypasses the security issues that would otherwise normally trigger a 404, but that also means a slower page the first time the page is visited.

I am only using the public file schema, but I would expect this to fail with the private file schema based styles.

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     */
    function MODULE_theme() {
      return array(
        'remote_image_style' => array(
          'variables' => array(
            'style_name' => NULL,
            'path' => NULL,
            'width' => NULL,
            'height' => NULL,
            'alt' => '',
            'title' => NULL,
            'attributes' => array(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    /**
     * Returns HTML for an image using a specific image style.
     *
     * Clones theme_image_style() with the additional step of forcing the creation
     * of the derivative to bypass any 404 issues.
     */
    function theme_remote_image_style($variables) {
      // Determine the dimensions of the styled image.
      $dimensions = array(
        'width' => $variables['width'],
        'height' => $variables['height'],
      );
      image_style_transform_dimensions($variables['style_name'], $dimensions);

      $variables['width'] = $dimensions['width'];
      $variables['height'] = $dimensions['height'];

      $image_style_dest_path = image_style_path($variables['style_name'], $variables['path']);
      if (!file_exists($image_style_dest_path)) {
        $style = image_style_load($variables['style_name']);
        image_style_create_derivative($style, $variables['path'], $image_style_dest_path);
      }
      $variables['path'] = file_create_url($image_style_dest_path);
      return theme('image', $variables);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`theme_image_style()` accepts a URI using PHP's stream wrappers and not real paths.

`input://` is a PHP's stream wrapper, whereas `public://`, `private://` and `temporary://` are Drupal's stream wrappers for representing the `sites/default/files`, private and temporary folders.

If you definitely need to use an image style with an image found in a module, you might want to check the [system_stream_wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/system_stream_wrapper) module which adds the **`module://`**, `theme://`, `profile://` and `library://` stream wrappers.

Notice: It may be irrelevant to the current question but since it was mentioned in other posts, I would like to also point to the [remote_stream_wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper) module which *adds support for any URL using http://, https://, or feed://*. As mentioned though, *these stream wrappers are read-only and cannot perform any writing operations* but I believe it could be used with `image_style_url()` and related functions like `theme_image_style()`.